# httplib in Python to get the status code...but it is too tricky?

Tags: python, regex, http, http-headers

```
>>> import httplib
>>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.google.com")
>>> conn.request("HEAD", "/index.html")
>>> res = conn.getresponse()
>>> print res.status, res.reason
200 OK
```

This code will get the HTTP status code.  However, notice that I split up "google.com" and "/index.html" on 2 lines.

And it's confusing.

What if I want to find the status code of just a general URL???

```
http://mydomain.com/sunny/boo.avi
http://anotherdomain.com/podcast.mp3
http://anotherdomain.com/rss/fee.xml
```

Can't I just stick the URL into it, and make it work?

Edit...I cannot use urllib, because I don't want to downlaod the file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternatively, if you expect that actually downloading the data is problematic and you really need the `HEAD` method, you could parse the URL using [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html):

```
>>> import httplib
>>> import urlparse
>>> url = "http://www.google.com/index.html"
>>> (scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment) = urlparse.urlparse(url)
>>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(netloc)
>>> conn.request("HEAD", urlparse.urlunparse(('', '', path, params, query, fragment))
>>> res = conn.getresponse()
>>> print res.status, res.reason
302 Found
```

And wrap this into a function taking the URL as an argument.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you are better off using the URL library instead?

In Python 2, use [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html):

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> url = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com/index.html")
>>> url.getcode()
200
```

In Python 3, use [`urllib.request`](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/urllib.request.html):

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> url = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.google.com/index.html")
>>> url.getcode()
200
```

Comment: +1, but as Yann notes below, this will download the whole page, not just the HEAD.

Comment: Quite right; see also my other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731657/httplib-in-python-to-get-the-status-code-but-it-is-too-tricky/1731800#1731800

Comment: @Stephan202, I tried Thomas's code with url `http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/linux-2.6.31.6.tar.bz2`, and watched my network traffic with `vnstat -l`. I couldn't find any sign that the file was being downloaded. Can you explain your assertion? Thanks!

Comment: As soon as you call, e.g., `readlines` on the returned object, you'll see your download meter starting to tick. Maybe some OS buffer fills up quickly, and since you don't empty it, the kernel stops sending `ACK`s and the server stops sending data?

Comment: But Thomas, the code you posted in your answer doesn't use readlines(). Do you believe the code above downloads the whole page? I can't find any evidence of that.

Comment: No, as I wrote it, it doesn't download (much). But clearly, it doesn't close the connection either. If you do this a few thousand times, the kernel might get real unhappy.

Answer (score 2):

The `connect` method takes a server argument (with an optional port). You have to split the connection with the resource you actually want.

For a simpler way to download web resources directly, you could go with `urllib2` but `urllib2` only supports GET or POST methods, no HEAD, so you end up downloading the whole resource.

Answer (score 0):

According to the `spec` you're supposed to split it up like that, maybe Python could abstract that out for you a bit, they're probably just giving you straight access to the header so you know exactly how it's being formatted, which is really the preference.

Answer (score 0):

I like urllib2, sample code:

```
import urllib2
res = urllib2.urlopen('http://google.com/index.html')
res.getCode() #contains code
```

I something went wrong, you'll get an exception you can catch.

**EDIT:** Thanks, changes `res.code` to `res.getCode()` since the second one is documented

Comment: The `code` field is undocumented. You should probably use `getcode()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that not all web servers support HEAD on each resource so you'll end up retrieving the resource anyway. You should write code accordingly.